# Problems trying to install Ubuntu 18.10 in Aspire A515-51

Tags: system-installation, raid, acer, 18.10

I just bought a new Aspire A515-51, and I tried to install Ubuntu 18.10 but I'm having trouble. When I have to select the partition where I want to install it, it doesn't show the `/dev/sda`: [screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rqVU.png)

How can I be able to install it?

Answer (score 0):

From screen you submitted looks like you can continue in the process. If you do not have any paralel system on notebook you probably will not damage anything.

dispositivo donde instalar el cargador de aaranque 
google translator: device where to install the boot loader

I suppose, that /dev/sda will be created through the installation. But rather wait for better answer. Also those + - buttons could create and delete partitions.

Comment: I have Windows 10 installed, and I want to have both installed. I found this quistion in a forum https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2003675 So I executed the command sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda, and now the installer shows, but doesn't let me make a partition to install, and Windows doesn't start. Do you know if there is a way to revert that?

Comment: actually I do not know. Probably I should not give advice. :) I flagged your comment, hope that someone else help. I do not know if

    sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda

is relevant in your case.

Comment: I think that was what caused the problem with the Windows because it stopped working after I executed that command.

Comment: @AdriánJuárez Have you solved the problem? I think you can ask another question regarding `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda` but also add details about installation process. I found general help in this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi. It could helped you at the beginning of the installation. Basically now you cannot boot either Windows and Ubuntu (which was not ever installed)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have figured out the solution after days of digging around with some of the articles on here. Here are the steps I followed. **Please be sure to read through the entire post before attempting as I did NOT want to dual boot and the steps listed will completely wipe windows off your laptop.**

1. Boot into Ubuntu with your liveUSB or liveCD.
2. Select "Try Ubuntu"
3. Once Ubuntu is up search in the Apps for GParted.
4. Select the main HDD, right click and format to ext4
5. Once that is complete go back to the main desktop screen and click the Install Ubuntu icon and follow the step for the installation.

This process worked for me and my Acer Aspire A515-51 installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The only difference is I wanted to run Ubuntu ONLY and not dual boot. However in the installer there is an option to run alongside and the only difference would be in step 4 to only partition part of the drive and not the whole thing like I did. just make sure you format it to ext4 Hope this helps.